# Where do ack-only sent packets come from (on FreeBSD)?

Tags: freebsd, tcpip, tcp

I run the systat -tcp command on a moderately loaded system and see something like this for a 5 second window:

```
                /0   /1   /2   /3   /4   /5   /6   /7   /8   /9   /10
 Load Average   ||||||||||||

         TCP Connections                       TCP Packets
       0 connections initiated           21062 total packets sent
     153 connections accepted            16291 - data
     153 connections established           125 - data (retransmit by dupack)
      11 connections dropped                 1 - data (retransmit by sack)
       0 - in embryonic state             4271 - ack-only
       5 - on retransmit timeout             0 - window probes
       0 - by keepalive                    217 - window updates
       0 - from listen queue                 0 - urgent data only
                                           148 - control
                                             0 - resends by PMTU discovery
         TCP Timers                      21057 total packets received
    9752 potential rtt updates           13471 - in sequence
   12437 - successful                       49 - completely duplicate
     763 delayed acks sent                  11 - with some duplicate data
     140 retransmit timeouts                14 - out-of-order
       0 persist timeouts                  225 - duplicate acks
       0 keepalive probes                12535 - acks
       0 - timeouts                          0 - window probes
                                            80 - window updates
                                             0 - bad checksum
```

Why is the sent ack-only number so much higher than the "delayed acks sent" number plus the dup data received numbers? What situations generate ack-only packets besides incoming data (which should go through delayed ack timer) and received dupes (immediate ack). Keepalive, I guess. But this box has no long-lived idle connections. Everything is short and furious. And there's a keepalive line item there too that says zero...

What am I missing about the tcp machine here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reasoning that ack-only packets should only be sent when the machine either gets a dupe, or when the timer expires, but I don't see why that would be true.  There is another category, perhaps more common and important than either of them, which is that the ack window is almost full.

If the other machine is streaming data to you and sends enough packets to get close to the ack window, the local machine will send it an ack.  In the common case that it has no other data to send back, it will send an ack-only packet.

So, why are there any delayed acks?  Because we don't want to ack every single packet the client sends: that would generate excessive back traffic.

Suppose the recv window would allow for 10 incoming packets.  The remote machine sends us one.  There is no need to ack it right away, because they know they can send us up to 9 more.  If they do in fact keep sending packets, then as we get close to filling the window, we'll acknowledge their transmissions.

On the other hand, if they send us just one packet, and then stop for a while, we do want to at least acknowledge we got that one packet, so that they know not to retransmit it and so they know the current state of the window.

The delayed ack timer distinguishes between these two cases: letting them carry on if they're sending lots of data, without letting data sit unacknowledged for too long.

Comment: +1 To summarize: most commonly when there are no other data packets to piggy-back an ack on to.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think I also misunderstood delayed-ack... it only affects a solitary packet. "Ack window" is the same as "recv window" in your usage? This is the comment from the DELAY_ACK macro in tcp_input.c: "Indicate whether this ack should be delayed.  We can delay the ack if
    - there is no delayed ack timer in progress and
    - our last ack wasn't a 0-sized window.  We never want to delay
        the ack that opens up a 0-sized window"

Comment: Yes, I meant the recv window.